# How to price my enterprise app?

Tags: android, blackberry

I was asked to develop an app on android and blackberry platforms.I thing its fairly straight forward app.Now I have to quote a price for them.I have never done something like this (I am still in collage) so I have no clue as to what would be a fair price.

Comment: This would fit better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: This is neither a programming question (and therefore StackOverflow is not the right place), nor a good one. How should we even answer that without knowing what your app is supposed to do or how much work it is/was to develop it?

Comment: Well, StackOverflow is more related to the programming than to the pricing of the apps. See the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq - I think you question belongs to StackEchange Programmers, see their FAQ: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: how bout giving it away for free? :)

Comment: @Ravi: The app is for a private companies internal use,its usefull for  no one else.

Comment: @Shlublu,@Clement Bellot: I thought it was part of development... Point noted.

Comment: @Vignesh: it is ok, no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with 18 euros per hour in Germany for a college student, but be aware your question is very complicated. Mobile development is an expert field yet, so commands a high price (just look at the amount of questions on SO that basically say "Hey I just started, how can I display hello world"). Therefore you can demand a bit of money.

However, if you live in a relatively inexpensive country such as some eastern european countries or India, you will have to demand less, as well as if you can be easily put on the line with those programmers. If you are good and are confident that your client will pay up, I would go around 1600 euros per two weeks of work, so if you work like 4 hours per day for two weeks in the evening, it's 800 euros. Adjust for dollars.

Don't forget to factor in bugs, or add a fixed price for maintenance. You would also be wise to negociate possible additions, and you can modulate with giving out the source or not (make it less expensive if you only turn out the APK, more expensive if the client gets the source code). Don't forget that if you have written your code in a modular way, you may also negociate that the modules are your personal libraries and may be reused in other projets.

Comment: And if you become really, really rich, you can always contact me and give me some of the money, or invite me on your private yacht to party!

Answer (score 0):

When you upload you application to android market and blackberry app world you would see the option for publishing free or paid app. so dont worry about that when you follow step by step process you will get option for that .  for blackberry you have to wait for paid publish your application ..first you have to publish free than wait around week or 10 days for release this application. one your application release you put your application for sale.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the amount of hours it would take you to develop the app then multiply it by the price per hour you're aiming to get.
Put another box for maintenance by giving a price per hour charge for any updates.